# How to extend data provider in react admin?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-admin

I'm using [react admin](https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin). And I have created a `DataProvider` from their [example implementation](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/DataProviders.html#example-implementation).

However, I had to change their login form from `username` to `email`. This means that now I should provide a custom [**Auth Provider**](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Authentication.html).

Now in my `authProvider.js` I want to connect to API. Based on their recommendation, it's better to extend `DataProvider` for any communication with API.

Since `login` is not any of the existing methods in `dataProvider`, thus I need to add methods to it.

I added two methods for general purpose API call:

```
const dataProvider = {
    // default methods => getList, create, ect.
    get: (url) => {
        return httpClient(`${apiUrl}/${url}`, {
            method: 'GET'
        });
    },

    post: (url, params) => {
        return httpClient(`${apiUrl}/${url}`, {
            method: 'POST',
            body: JSON.stringify(params)
        });
    }
```

And then inside my `authProvider.js` I use it:

```
const authProvider = {
    // authentication
    login: params => {
        dataProvider.post('/login', params).then(result => {
            console.log(result);
        });
    },
```

Now I'm stuck at this point on how to wire them together. I receive this error when I press `login` button on my login form:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined

(anonymous function)
node_modules/ra-core/esm/auth/useLogin.js:39
  36 | var nextSearch = locationState && locationState.nextSearch;
  37 | var login = useCallback(function (params, pathName) {
  38 |     if (params === void 0) { params = {}; }
> 39 |     return authProvider.login(params).then(function (ret) {
     | ^  40 |         dispatch(resetNotification());
  41 |         var redirectUrl = pathName
  42 |             ? pathName

submit
src/Auth/LoginForm.js:67
  64 | 
  65 | const submit = values => {
  66 |     setLoading(true);
> 67 |     login(values, redirectTo)
     | ^  68 |         .then(() => {
  69 |             setLoading(false);
  70 |         })
```

What should I return from my custom methods? How can I wire them together?

**Update**
I know I can use `Promise` with `resolve` and `reject` methods. But I want to use the `react-admin`'s internal pipeline and logic as much as I can. For example, I don't want to implement HTTP status check in my custom `get` and `post` methods in my `dataProvider.js`. They have this logic in their `fetch.js` file and I want to be able to use that.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to use the dataProvider for auth related requests. Use fetch or any libraries you want (axios or any other). For information, none of the authProvider we developer for clients used the dataProvider. They have two very distinct jobs

Comment: But I want to get into the overall pipeline of what they do. Parsing the response, showing notifications automatically for errors, appending appropriate headers, etc. I lose all of this when I use another library.

Comment: Also they don't have distinct jobs. Data provider is the adapter of API. This was a quote from the documentation. Any call to API should be able to implemented inside data provider. Any type of communication.

Comment: No they do. I'm one of the core maintainers. You might want to reuse the httputils functions but that's it. We separated those features for a reason

Comment: The notifications are handled by react-admin when it call the authprovider. I suggest you read its dedicated documentation again

Comment: I'll extend the answer with more details soon though

Comment: I didn't know that you are a maintainer. In that case I recommend that you stick to your docs and make data provider a true API adapter. Because it's much easier to have one central place that does all the API communication, than to break it. Any communication with any API = data.

Comment: "Any communication with any API = data."  this may be pedantically true, but it is overly simplistic. Sure, at the end of the day you are getting/posting to a URL, but there is a meaningful real-world distinction between data-fetching and app authorization/authentication.